# Single Sign On using SAML implementation with JBOSS 4.3 server

Tags: single-sign-on

We are trying to design a Single Sign On using SAML implementation.  Our application uses JBOSS 4.3 server.  Based on research JBOSS 4.3 does not support SAML standards.  Anyone who has same experienced?  What alternative  can we used for this scenario.